# fetchedResultsController core data fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: uitableview, swift, core-data, null, optional-values

I know there are innumerable questions with the same error but none of the solutions seemed to work.

I want to make a blog reader app that saves and fetches data from the CoreData. I am able to save the JSON results into the CoreData, but when i try to retrieve it to display in the tableView, it crashes with `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on line

`let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Blog", inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext!)`

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

var activeItem:String = ""

class CenterViewController: UIViewController,
  UIWebViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,     
 SidePanelViewControllerDelegate {
 var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
 var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var webview2: UIWebView!


var delegate: CenterViewControllerDelegate?

// MARK: Button actions

@IBAction func kittiesTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
delegate?.toggleLeftPanel?()
 }

@IBAction func puppiesTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
delegate?.toggleRightPanel?()
 }

  func animalSelected(animal: Animal) {

var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
var newBlogItem:NSManagedObject
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
var error : NSError?

 let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(animal.url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

    if (error != nil){
        println(error)

    }else{


       let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
        var posts = [[String:String]()]

        var post:AnyObject

        var authorDictionary:AnyObject
        var newBlogItem:NSManagedObject
        for var i = 0; i < jsonResult["posts"]!.count; i++

        {
        posts.append([String:String]())
        post = jsonResult["posts"]![i] as NSDictionary
        posts[i]["title"] = post["title"] as? NSString
        posts[i]["publishedDate"] = post["date"] as? NSString
        posts[i]["content"] = post["content"] as? NSString
        authorDictionary = post["author"] as NSDictionary
        posts[i]["author"] = post["name"] as? NSString



            newBlogItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Blog", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
            newBlogItem.setValue(posts[i]["title"], forKey: "title")
            newBlogItem.setValue(posts[i]["publishedDate"], forKey: "publishedDate")
            newBlogItem.setValue(posts[i]["content"], forKey: "content")
            newBlogItem.setValue(posts[i]["author"], forKey: "author")

            context.save(nil)

        }
        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Blog")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)
        println(results)

  }

})

task.resume()
   delegate?.collapseSidePanels?()
}

// MARK: - Table View

 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {


    return self.fetchedResultsController.sections!.count
  // return 1
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
   return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
   //return 20
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
  // self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
   cell.textLabel?.text = "blog item"
    return cell
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        context.deleteObject(self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject)

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !context.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}

func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject
    cell.textLabel?.text = object.valueForKey("title")!.description
}



// MARK: - Fetched results controller

var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
        }

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Blog", inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext!)
        fetchRequest.entity = entity?

        // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "publishedDate", ascending: false)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
        // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
        let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Slide Out Tutorial")
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !_fetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return _fetchedResultsController!
}
var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableview.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        self.tableview.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        self.tableview.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:
        return
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        tableview.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        tableview.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Update:
        self.configureCell(tableview.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    case .Move:
        tableview.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        tableview.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:
        return
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableview.endUpdates()
}
```

}

The tableview displays the text "blog item" for 20 times when i return 1 and return 20 from  `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and from `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` respectively, and data is displayed in the console. But when i comment out the manual return vales, and want to use the orignal ones, the app crashes on the line mentioned above.

I am jst guessing if it has something to do with the `fetchedResultsController`.

Pls help. m stuck on this since yesterday

Comment: You need to set the value of self.managedObjectContext, it is initialised to nil and then never set.

Comment: @pbasdf can you pls help me with how to do that..m new to swift and have  managed to reach here by mixing different individual projects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `self.managedObjectContext` (it is currently nil and that is causing your error).  You could set it in one of the functions called early in the life of the view controller, such as `viewDidLoad`, but another way would be to set it when initialising the fetchedResultsController, like this:

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }
    var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    self.managedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Blog", inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext!)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity?
    ...
```

Comment: also found I forgot to instantiate my context, one place I wasn't looking, thanks!!

Comment: @pbasdf oh man! you just saved my life! thanks. I've been trying to get my head around this for like 8 hours going step by step in the debugger... Thanks!